# Visual studio C# rdlc report issue

Tags: c#, report

I have this problem: in a C# standalone application I have this A4 (29,7 x 21 cm) rdlc report.
The problem is that the report is not filled always well.

In the report there is the body section (with the 3 rectangles with text, a title and a description) and a tablix,  and the footer section with the total and some static text (see the next 2 images of a report that has the problem):

[image]
[image]

And here is a report that is OK:

[image]

The first report has 2 pages but the first page has the (red) empty space and then the content goes to the second page.

When there are just a few record the report is ok (the second report) and the whole content fits in one page.

**So the problem is how to do to fill every page exactly from the top to the bottom** (in case of many pages); then the last page should be ok by itself as in both examples, with the rest of the records and the footer.

I tried all the combinations of the properties of the elements (whole report, body, footer, textbox, etc, etc) but the content never fills exactly the whole page.
The height of the rows is not fixed so I cannot calculate how many record should fit on one page.

I have Windows 10 and Visual Studio 12 (2014), .NET Framework 4.8.

Thanx